# Get HTML text from page after scrolling

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I am trying to capture HTML text from a page, in the case of this website more info is loaded dynamically as you scroll.  So it is easy enough to capture the first page of text, but have do I get the next.  I have the auto scroll part worked out fine like this:

```
string Java = "javascript:window.scroll(0,";//Builds up logic so screen will scroll by one page each time
string JavaScroll = Java + Scroll + ");";

webBrowser1.Navigate(JavaScroll);

Scroll += 3050;

String Morefriends = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
```

The problem is, even when I scroll, the Morefriends HTML text still remains the same as the first page, like it is not updating to reflect the HTML text from the new page that was just scrolled to.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to do this entirely in javascript?

Comment: I really only know C#. I found the auto scroll part somewhere else and just incorporated it into my program.  If you can show me how to do it in java script that would be fine.